# Why my messaging.getToken() works in firefox but not in chrome?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get the current registration token. I am printing the token to the console once I get it. This works on firefox but not on chrome. It does not throw me an error. Instead, the request gets timed out.

```js
messaging
  .getToken()
  .then(function(currentToken) {
    if (currentToken) {
      console.log(currentToken);
      // sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
      // updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
    } else {
      // Show permission request.
      console.log(
        "No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one."
      );
      // Show permission UI.
      // updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
      // setTokenSentToServer(false);
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log("An error occurred while retrieving token. ", err);
    // showToken("Error retrieving Instance ID token. ", err);
    // setTokenSentToServer(false);
  });
})
.catch(function(err) {
  console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.", err);
});
```

Comment: If you inspected the request (using `developer-tools`) in chrome - does it deffer from the same request in Firefox? (mainly headers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on OS X with chrome 77.0.3865.90, while firefox gave me a correct token too. My "solution" was to clear the site data, close all chrome instances, reopened chrome and then it worked for me. The same strange behavior is described in [this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/issues/334#issuecomment-519889899).